# Find a divisor that's no less than a given number - optimization

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers

This is a repost from a question on Russian Stack Overflow.

The original task is:

> For two given integer numbers s and p, s<=p, find a number d so that s<=d; p%d=0 and for any number x, s < x < d, p%x is nonzero.

The solution proposed is as simple as it could be. For the numbers (s, sqrt(p)) try dividing p by the number, if a number with zero remainder is found, return that number. If neither resulted in a zero remainder, do the same for (s-1,1) backwards, and for a found x, return p/x.

How can one optimize this algorithm? I'm thinking that factorization of p is an optimization if either p is prime, or p is a multiplication of several small primes. So I think that one can factorize p, create a list of all possible divisors of p based on factorization, and find the one that's just above s, and return that. Are there any more optimizations possible? And is this an optimization at all?

Comment: P%S == 0 or P%S != 0 is there  any property like that?

Comment: @karthik These are strict inequations, so if s==d, there are no numbers `x` to check the third condition. Say p=30,s=4 -> d is 5, there are no integer x that are 4 < x < 5. p=39, s=4 -> d is 13, x in [5..12] and neither divides p.

Comment: Find all factors of `P` and find first factor which is greater than `S`? doesn't it work?

Comment: @karthik Well it does, I wonder if it's any optimization, and how far into size of p it becomes an optimization. But those factors must not contain only primes, because say p=27, s=4 - the answer should be 9, and 9 is not prime. p=36, s=5 - the answer should be 6, a composite of two primes.

Comment: I din't mean prime factors, I meant all factors.

Comment: Then yes, but I have proposed exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

You can always start with `p/2` and work down with `p/next-prime` until s. This is guaranteed to find the largest number that can evenly divide the number p.

`def f(s, p) {
    prime = 2 
    while((divisor = p / prime) > s) {
        if(p % prime == 0) return divisor
        prime = next_prime(prime)
    }
    return 1  // prime
}`

The real optimization opportunity is if the next_prime() results can be cached, or precomputed.

Edit: Corrected to `return divisor` instead of `return p`

Comment: No, that won't work. Input data: p=30, s=4, your algorithm would immediately return 30 (O_O) and even if it's a typo, returning 15 isn't a correct answer. The proper answer is 5.

Comment: Could you give the steps of how you arrived at 5?

Comment: 30%5=0, 5>=4, 30%4 !=0.

Comment: So, you are looking for the smallest number > p, not just any number < s

Comment: Yep, but you have switched parameters, p is always greater than s, and I need the smallest number that divides p and is not less than s.